# ORACLE Listagg with an Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I need to pull data from two tables where two values match.  The joining table produces 5 rows, and will always produce 5 rows.

Is there a way that I can take one column with distinct values and return multiple columns in a single row?

For an example:
Table A:
orig_zip, dest_zip, pri_mode

Table B:
orig_zip, dest_zip, serv_comm

Table B will always return 5 results for every 1 result in Table A when doing an inner join like the following:

```
SELECT a.orig_zip, a.dest_zip, b.serv_comm, a.pri_mode
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
ON a.orig_zip = b.orig_zip and a.dest_zip = b.dest_zip
ORDER BY a.orig_zip, a.dest_zip, b.mail_class;
```

How can I take the 5 results, and turn them into a single row in oracle.  The only field that is different in the results will be the serv_comm field.

The final row should have the following setup:

[ORIG_ZIP][DEST_ZIP][SERV_COMM1][SERV_COMM2][SERV_COMM3][SERV_COMM4][SERV_COMM5][PRI_MODE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research, and here is the answer on SQL Fiddle!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/783b8/1/0

Answer (score 0):

From 11g you can also do it with the PIVOT clause:

```
FROM  trans_mode a
INNER JOIN servcomm b
ON a.orig_zip = b.orig_zip and a.dest_zip = b.dest_zip
pivot
(
  max(serv_comm)
  for (mail_class)
  in ('PRI' AS pri_serv, 'FCM' AS fcm_serv, 'PER' AS per_serv, 'PKG' AS pkg_serv, 'STD' AS std_serv)
  );
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo (based on yours)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/783b8/15)